# How to wire a lamp socket when both screws are gold?9

Tags: wiring, lighting, light-fixture, light

I have a lamp socket that only has brass screws.  How do I know which one is hot?  I believe it is the the one that connects to the “tab” that the bulb touches.

Comment: Does not matter for most lamps, they will be happy either way.  For people you would like to keep hot far away from fingers, so centre tab is what most people like to use.

Answer (score 5):

Medium base E26 (1") Lampholders are normally rated for 250v and can be wired for [US 240v bulbs](https://amzn.to/3BvF1fi) with two hot conductors, so screw color for polarization is inappropriate. However, NEC 410.50 specifies that when a "grounded conductor" (which is the name the NEC normally uses for the neutral) is connected to a luminaire, it shall be connected to the screw shell.

So your thought was correct: with a 120v connection that leaves the center "tab" as the switched hot.